# How can I create a landing page with dynamic paragraph text per each user?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, excel

Is there a best method to creating a simple landing splash page that displays information dynamically?

Example - One user might see on their landing page that their total ticket allotment is 10, while another user will see that they get 6 tickets.

Hoping to find a way that I can target 10 different emails that display the same landing page for all, but the information is slightly different based on the email it was sent to. Maybe a JSON pull or the site somehow reads off a row or column from a CSV file? Not sure the best method here.

I don't have any code written for this just yet, but wanted to hear possible approaches or best practices.

Comment: How are users being identified in the page? Via a Login or just by the email link?

Comment: Hi @DocPython - Just emailed a link. I would have their emails and first name and last. So if I sent you an email that linked to the page, it ideally would say: 

Hi, DocPython

Your email is DocPython@gmail.com (example) and you have 6 total tickets. 

But, the same email will be sent to someone else and their name, email, and total tickets would be different. However, layout and design would stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said the users will be identified only with the link they recieve your best option is to send some information in the link itself.

I will propose two options:

### Sending plain information

If that data isn't sensitive or it is just for informative purposes, you could send it in the **query params** like this:

> http://example.com/tickets?firstname=John&lastname=Smith&tickets=6&mail=jsmith@example.com

Although it would work I wouldn't recommend it.

### Using a database

If you'll have a backend server/api you can store the data that needs to be displayed in a database or a file.
I'll give you an example with an SQL database:

```
| Id | fistname | lastname | email              | tickets |
|----|----------|----------|--------------------|---------|
| 1  | John     | Smith    | jsmith@example.com | 6       |
| 2  | ...      | ...      | ...                | ...     |
```

Then your link would just include the id of the row which information you need.

> http://example.com/tickets?id=1

Notes that this aproach is much more secure than the alternative but can be improved further if you don't use auto_incremental ids for example.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is super helpful DocPhthon! Two questions. 

1. Would I need to know PHP for the database method? Only know HTML, CSS, and JS. 

2. Would there be a way to hide that "?ID=1" so the user doesn't just switch it to "2" or "3" to see another users allotment of tickets?

Comment: 1- Yes, for database access you'll need to use a backend. It can be coded in PHP or any languaje you'd like.

2 - You could "hide" the id applying some kind of encryption to it before sending it to the user and decoding it when the link is accessed but I cannot give you a great advise for this matter, you probably can find lots of ways online.

If the answer was helpful please mark it as accepted.